# When validating geometries, what are "Nested shells"?

Tags: python, geometry, fme-form, shapely, ogc

I am validating shapefiles polygon geometry using shapely, and have also attempted it using FME. Some polygons return the error "`Nested Shells`".

I cannot find a definition of what the problem is, whether in FME documentation ([here](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FME_Transformers.htm#Transformers/geometryvalidator_issues.htm)) or in google search results on shapely or OGC geometry validation.

Would anyone have a definition or (ideally!) a graphic example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A Nested Shell is a polygon on top of another polygon.

[image: Nested shell]

[Image source](https://marswiki.jrc.ec.europa.eu/wikicap/index.php/LPISQA_3.b.ii_LPISQA_portal_automatic_screening)

Comment: OK, many thanks!! It sounded to me like something way more complicated, but this is easy to address.

Comment: What did you end up doing to address this?